# nodejs - ssh2 server connection is not giving any output or errors

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am fairly new to nodejs. I am trying to simply connect to my webserver below with a host, port, username and password and get the up time response as shown below. executing the file from commandline is not giving me any output, it just gives me an empty commandline. removing any of ip, port or username/pwd is throwing me errors though. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

        var conn = new Client();
        conn.on('ready', function() {
          console.log('Client :: ready');
          conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
              console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
              conn.end();
            }).on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            });
          });
        }).connect({
          host: '192.168.100.100',
          port: 2122,
          username: '!@#!@#!@',
          password: '!@#!@#!'
        });


    // example output: 
    // Client :: ready 
    // STDOUT:  17:41:15 up 22 days, 18:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05 
    // 
    // Stream :: exit :: code: 0, signal: undefined 
    // Stream :: close
```

Comment: What does `npm ls` show? Does it show `ssh2-streams` v0.1.11, or is it an older version of that module? If it shows v0.1.11, can you set `debug: console.log` in your `connect()` options and post the output in a gist or paste somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an `'error'` event handler to the actual connection object prior to any other handler.

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();

conn.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('SSH - Connection Error: ' + err);
});

conn.on('end', function() {
  console.log('SSH - Connection Closed');
});

conn.on('ready', function() {
  // code to work with SSH
});

conn.connect({
  host: '192.168.100.100',
  port: 2122,
  username: '!@#!@#!@',
  password: '!@#!@#!'
});
```

Comment: I tried it, there are no errors yet there is no out put. I'm assuming the connection is made but the output is a blank commandline and goes back to next line in cmd

Comment: @LisaA just so you know, I ran into similar problems where `ssh2` wasn't doing anything until I stopped method chaining on the connection object. Have you tried setting your code up just like I did in my code sample above? For whatever reason when I kept doing `conn.on('').on('').connect()` for instance, and nothing would happen. When I broke each function out onto `conn` separately, like above, it worked.

Comment: conn.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('SSH - Connection Error: ' + err);
});

conn.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;
      stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
        console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
        conn.end();
      });
      stream.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
      });
    });
});

Comment: I broke it down, still no luck.

Comment: @LisaA, just looked at your port in your connection options. Are you sure that you're supposed to connect over `2122`? Typically SSH operates over port 22.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Doing below resolved it -

```
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
```